# django braces UserPassesTestMixin redirects to 'accounts/profile/'

Tags: django, permissions

I'm adding django-braces to a system to ensure only certain users can perform certain actions. As a background, I've got some users who login and potentially have other users associated with their account, like a team leader.

Those team leaders are able to edit the details of their team so I've got a `UserPassesTestMixin` on that edit view and a `LoginRequiredMixin` on the dashboard view once they login.

Here are my views;

```
class Dashboard(DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'online_entry/entrant/dashboard.html'
    model = FreeCycleEntrant
    http_method_names = ['get']

class UpdateEntrantWizard(SignupWizard, UserPassesTestMixin):
    template_name = 'online_entry/entrant/wizard_form.html'
    form_list = [EditTeamMember]
    model = Entrant
    instance = None

    def get_instance_obj(self):
        if self.instance is None and 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            self.instance = get_object_or_404(
                Entrant, pk=self.kwargs['pk']
            )
        return self.instance

    def test_func(self, user):
        parent = Entrant.objects.get(user=user)
        return self.get_instance_obj().user_has_access(user, parent=parent)
```

And the test function on my `Entrant` model is quite straightforward;

```
def user_has_access(self, user, parent=None):
    """
    Indicates whether or not a user can edit this user. The passed in user
    is the logged in user.
    :type self: object
    """
    if self.user == user:
        return True
    if isinstance(user, AnonymousUser):
        return False
    if parent and self.parent_entrant == parent:
        return True
    return False
```

So when I'm logged in as one of these users, and from the `Dashboard` attempt to go to that `UpdateEntrantWizard` view I'm redirected to `/accounts/profile/` before the tests are hit (using breakpoints).

Am I missing something in my implementation of braces? It looks like you really only need to add the test & the mixin to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

`UserPassesTestMixin` [inherits from `AccessMixin`](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py#L25), which includes the `login_url` property. Simply set:

```
login_url = "/your_url/"
```

and it will redirect to a url of your choice.

As far as testing is concerned you can use the [django `Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client). The example below from an app of mine should give the idea here. Obviously the user 'Claire' in this test should be created where the ellipses are, and with the permissions needed to pass the test.

```
def test_home_url_allows_authenticated_user(self):
    c = Client()
    ...
    c.login(username='Claire', password='pass')
    content = c.get('/travel/')
    self.assertEqual(content.status_code, 200)
```

Finally you may want to add a message in your login page along these lines:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h2>You're logged in, but you might not have permission to view the page you requested.</h2>
{% else %}
...
```

Because that's where users will end up if they don't have the right permissions.

Comment: Oh that was in the docs as optional. Can you add it to a class as a `reverse()` as these are in use on functions with args

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question — please see my edit.

Comment: Do you mean it redirects to `login_url` if it passes the test? Mine doesn't even execute the test before the redirect.

Comment: @marksweb that's usually an indication that the user you're logged in as doesn't have the permissions you think they do in my experience. To confirm you can log in as a superuser and try it, which should work. To be clear, there should be no redirect if you're logged in and have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching

```
class UpdateEntrantWizard(SignupWizard, UserPassesTestMixin):
```

To

```
class UpdateEntrantWizard(UserPassesTestMixin, SignupWizard):
```

When using something like :

```
class SomeProtectedView(views.LoginRequiredMixin,
                    views.PermissionRequiredMixin,
                    TemplateView):
```

the order in which you call the mixins matter. In this example it will check if user is logged in before checking permissions. And, if you were to put TemplateView first it would bypass the mixins altogether.